# MySQL query using sprintf in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing query that uses sprintf to incorporate a php and mysql into a custom MySQL query.

This works great:

```
$query_EmpVSP = sprintf("SELECT * FROM HTG_VSP WHERE HomeOfEmpNumber IS NULL OR HomeOfEmpNumber = '' OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text"));
```

I need to add a second OR statement for another column called CustomForEmpNumber and want to re-use the $colname_EmpVSP value.

When I add

`. "OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text"));`

I get a invalid syntax at %s

Here is the current query that shows the error:

```
$query_EmpVSP = sprintf("SELECT * FROM HTG_VSP WHERE HomeOfEmpNumber IS NULL OR HomeOfEmpNumber = '' OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text") . " OR CustomForEmpNumber = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text"));
```

Comment: what mysql driver are you using? if you use `PDO` you could just parameterize your parameters eliminating the whole `sprintf()` stuff.

Comment: I have to use sprintf(), its an existing application and everything else is coded that way. @austin

Comment: so you want `SELECT * FROM HTG_VSP WHERE HomeOfEmpNumber IS NULL OR HomeOfEmpNumber = '' OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s` ? i ask because i'm having a little trouble understanding your end result based on what you post.

Comment: no, you don't need sprintf. `$x = "foo $bar baz"` is functionally identical to `$x = sprintf('foo %s baz', $bar);`. the strings you get will be IDENTICAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM HTG_VSP WHERE HomeOfEmpNumber IS NULL OR HomeOfEmpNumber = '' OR HomeOfEmpNumber = %s or CustomForEmpNumber = %s"; 
$query_EmpVSP = sprintf($sql,GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text"),GetSQLValueString($colname_EmpVSP, "text"));
```