# mysql_error %s in WHERE OR clause

Tags: php, mysql

```
$colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname = $_POST['txt_search'];    
$sql_rs_txtSearch = sprintf("SELECT * FROM staffstu WHERE lastname = %s OR 
                    firstname = %s ORDER BY lastname, firstname ASC", 
                    GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname, "text", 
                    $colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname, "text"));
```

It always gives

> mysql_error

If I do not use "sprintf" that's working fine. I can't find the solution.

Comment: You need to enclose string constants in single quotes.  So, use `'%s'` for the pattern in the string.

Comment: thanks a lot Gordon, I will try it when back to office. May I ask that if only one %s in the statement, why no need to enclose? thanks!

Comment: Hi Gordon, i just tried to enclose by single quotes but same error.

Comment: @faifai Could you echo the string (query), it will be easy to point out error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156640/mysql-query-using-sprintf-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a parameter for the second `%s`! You should get the following PHP warning

> Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments

```
$colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname = $_POST['txt_search'];    
$sql_rs_txtSearch = sprintf("SELECT * FROM staffstu WHERE lastname = %s OR 
                firstname = %s ORDER BY lastname, firstname ASC", 
                GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname, "text", 
                $colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname, "text"), <missing_param>);
```

I think you want this (check if it is correct)

```
$colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname = $_POST['txt_search'];    
$sql_rs_txtSearch = sprintf("SELECT * FROM staffstu WHERE lastname = '%s' OR 
                firstname = '%s' ORDER BY lastname, firstname ASC", 
                GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname, "text"), 
                GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_txtSearchLastname, "text"));
```

You should not use the mysql_* functions. More information here: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks sebastianbrosch, it work now after added your suggested arguments and remove the type of variable ($colname_rs_txtSearchFirstname)